# How to fix segmenation fault in this simple encryption program?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, encryption

I copied this exactly from the book I am reading after making multiple attempts at writing this program. I continue to get the same segmentation fault error.

This is the book, the chapter 7: Pointers program. 
https://www.barnesandnoble.com/p/c-programming-for-the-absolute-beginner-michael-vine/1101415261/2678286102503?st=PLA&sid=BNB_DRS_New+Marketplace+Shopping+Textbooks_00000000&2sid=Google_&sourceId=PLGoP211448&gclid=CjwKCAjw06LZBRBNEiwA2vgMVU96G7-LHaUncLG9FGCb6hq96xniJRdf0InjdEqM7qFs4-ETXXwzURoC3lYQAvD_BwE

The debugger is saying "Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffffffff000", which is the address of sMessage[0]. I'm not sure why I can't access the contents of the array.

Lastly, please forgive my horrible formatting. It's my first time asking a question.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    // function prototypes
    void encrypt(char [], int);
    void decrypt(char [], int);

    main()
    {

char myString[21] = {'\0'};
int iSelection = 0;
int iRand;

srand(time(NULL));

iRand = (rand() % 4); // random #, 1-4
system("clear");

printf("okay");

while( iSelection != 4) {

    printf("\n\n1\tEncrypt Clear Text");
    printf("\n2\tDecrypt Cipher Text");
    printf("\n3\tGenerate New Key");
    printf("\n4\tQuit");
    printf("\nSelect a Cryptography Option:");
    scanf("%d", &iSelection);
    switch (iSelection) {

        case 1:
        system("clear");
        printf("\nEnter clear text: ");
        scanf("%s", &iSelection);
        encrypt(myString, iRand);
        break;

        case 2:
        system("clear");
        printf("\nEnter cipher text: ");
        scanf("%s", &iSelection);
        encrypt(myString, iRand);
        break;

        case 3:
        system("clear");
        iRand = (rand() % 4); // random #, 1-4
        printf("\nNew Key Generated\n");
        break;
    } // end switch
} // end while loop
    } // end main

    void encrypt(char sMessage[], int random)
    {
int x = 0;

// encrypt the message by shifting each characters ASCII value
while (sMessage[x] != "\0") {
    sMessage[x] += random;
    x++;
} // end while loop
x = 0;
printf("Encrypted message is: ");

// print encrypted messsage
while (sMessage[x] != "\0") {
    printf("%c", sMessage[x]);
    x++;
} // end while loop
    } // end encrypt function

    void decrypt(char sMessage[], int random)
    {
int x=0;
x=0;

// decrypt the message by shifting each characters ASCII value
while (sMessage[x] != '\0') {
    sMessage[x] = sMessage[x] - random;
    x++;
} // end loop

x = 0;
printf("\n Decrypted Message is: ");

// print decrypted message
while (sMessage[x] != '\0') {
printf("%c", sMessage[x]);
x++;

} // end while loop

    } // end decrypt function
```

Comment: And I bet there were warnings?

Comment: Instead of saying "please forgive my horrible formatting" it would be much better to actually format the code so that people don't have to do it to help you. Your editor should be able to do it for you automatically BTW.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference between "\0" (double quote) and '\0' (single quote). The first is a pointer to a 'string' literal (constant), and the second is a character literal constant. One is a pointer to char(acter), the other is char(acter).

Do this to illustrate:

```
printf("%p\n", "\0");
printf("%d\n", '\0');
```

You use them interchangeably (*Python, Ruby, Perl, and R basically allow this*), the first is incorrect, the second is correct.

```
//don't do this
while (sMessage[x] != "\0") {
    sMessage[x] += random;
    x++;
}

//do this
while ('\0' != sMessage[x]) {
    sMessage[x] -= random;
    x++;
}
```

Actually, the best thing to do is define a constant (either #define or const),

```
#define EOS ('\0')
const char EOS = ('\0');
while (EOS != sMessage[x]) { //this is why I prefer #define literal
```

Note that Ruby and Perl allow string 'interpolation' on double-quoted strings, and do not allow string 'interpolation' on single quoted string.

But even more important is to guard against walking off the end of strings, so pass the length of sMessage, and check that as you traverse the array. This is why for(;;) repetition structures exist.

```
void encrypt(char buffer[], size_t len, int random)
...
for( x=0; x<len && (EOS != sMessage[x]; ++x ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In options 1 and 2 where you prompt the user to enter a string you are doing:

```
scanf("%s", &iSelection);
```

This is clearly wrong because the `iSelection` variable is an `int` but the `"%s"` format specifier requires a string. I think you meant to do this instead:

```
scanf("%s", myString);
```